# How can I set the limit of all elements in an array?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an array of c (10 elements) and I want to calculate the limit of the equation below when c(i)->0 (i = 1...10). How Can I express that c(i)->0 (i = 1...10) in the equation?

$$
\lim_{c(i)\to 0} \, \frac{1}{\frac{1000 \rho -\sum _{i=1}^{10} c(i) M(i)}{\text{Ms}}+\sum _{i=1}^{10} c(i)}
$$

The code I have is listed below.

```
Array[c, 10]
Limit[1/(\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(10\)]\(c[i]\)\) + (1000 \[Rho] - \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(10\)]\(c[i]\ M[i]\)\))/Ms), c[i] -> 0]
```

The output I got is below.

```
-(Ms/(-1000 \[Rho] - Ms (c[1] + c[2] + c[3] + c[4] + c[5] + c[6] + c[7] + c[8] + c[9] + c[10]) + c[1] M[1] + c[2] M[2] + c[3] M[3] + c[4] M[4] + c[5] M[5] + c[6] M[6] + c[7] M[7] + c[8] M[8] + c[9] M[9] + c[10] M[10]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first define an expression for what you are interested in:

```
expr = 1/(Sum[c[i], {i, 1, 10}] + (1000*\[Rho] - Sum[c[i] M[i], {i, 1, 10}])/Ms);
```

In your case the limit is trivial, since you can just set all `c[i]` to zero and get a finite result:

```
expr/.c[_]->0
```

> `Ms/(1000 \[Rho])`

(Here the underscore `_` means that all `c[x]` expressions will get replaced by the same `0` regardless of what `x` is.)
If you want to take all `c[i]` to zero carefully, you could do:

```
Series[expr/.c[x_]->eps c[x],{eps,0,0}]//Normal
```

> `Ms/(1000 \[Rho])`

Here we first replaced each `c[i]` by `eps c[i]` and then made a series expansion around `eps=0` to leading order. (The `Limit` function is less flexible than `Series`. Try to get used to using `Series` for your limit calculation needs.)

Comment: Many thanks! This is what I need!